# Convert excel to parquet file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I have a big excel file with some columns containing free text data which have long sentences.
I have to convert this into parquet format to ingest into warehouse.
I cannot convert it into csv because those columns having long sentences have comma.Tab-delimited is also not working.

Any suggestions here , how to convert this type of excel file to parquet format using python ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 7):

You can use pandas to read the file and export it as a parquet file:

```
import pandas

# Read the Excel file
df = pandas.read_excel('my_data.xlsx')

# Write the Parquet file
df.to_parquet('my_data.parquet')
```

Comment: Just make sure, openpyxl, pyarrow is installed before running the above code.

Answer (score 0):

it might be possible to convert it to a csv, delimeted by `;` instead of `,`.

If not you can try reading it into pandas, then exporting to parquet.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-csv-in-python/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Answer (score 0):

Start by [reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) the Excel into data frame.
Next [convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html?highlight=to_parquet#pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet) the data frame into parquet

Answer (score 0):

You could try the route over ODBC. This is probably only feasable for windows users though. You can download the Microsoft Excel ODBC driver here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

There is a python script writing the contents of an ODBC data source to parquet:
https://github.com/rondunn/odbc2parquet/blob/master/odbc2parquet.py

If you do not care about involving Python you colud also use the `odbc2parquet` command line tool (https://github.com/pacman82/odbc2parquet).

```sh
odbc2parquet -vvv query -c "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};Dbq=./test.xls;" test.par "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

On many windows systems you find a 32 Bit Excel ODBC driver preinstalled. Should you want to use that, you must make sure to either use the 32Bit variant of the command line tool.